# Node js Multi tenant with MySQL Sequelize ORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a multi-tenant using `nodejs` and `MySQL`, `sequelize as ORM`. Here I am trying to use separate `databases` for the tenants.

I have save the tenant details in `shared` `database` like this.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|tenantId   |   databaseHost    |   databaseName    |   databaseUserName    |   databasePassword|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1          |   localhost       |   tenant-1        |   root                |                   |
|2          |   localhost       |   tenant-2        |   root                |                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This kind of application already there in `knex` https://www.theblueflamelabs.com/multi-tenant-application-on-node-js/

But I want to implement in  `MySQL Sequelize ORM`

So, please suggest me any `blog` or `ideas` to create Node js Multi tenant application with `MySQL Sequelize ORM`